# Change gridview header text when i choose dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some doubt
This is my coding for aspx page and .cs page
How can I achieve the following 
If i select February the header text assigned January value and i select march then assign February value...Could you please help me find a solution for it

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="8-14">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtWeek2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In .CS page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
DropDownList1.Items.Add("Select");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("January");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("February");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("March");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("April");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("May");

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.169.10.22;Initial Catalog=SHRICITYUNO;User ID=uno;Password=uno");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cn.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Week1 FROM Finman_FundPlan", cn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
}

}


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string s = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "January")
{
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "29-31";
}
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "February")
{
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "-";
}
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "March")
{
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "29-31";
}
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "April")
{
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "29-30";
}
else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "May")
{
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
this.GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "29-31";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using Javascript at client side.
if you observe the grid view then you can notice that row[0] is the header row for gridview.
now you can check decide the which cell test you have to change.
see the following javascript function to accomplish your task

```
<script language="Javascript"> 
function ChangeHeaderText()
{
   var gridObject = document.getElementById("Gridview1"); 
   gridObject.rows[0].cells[0].innerText = 'NewHeader Text'; 
   return false; 
} 
</script>

//call above function on 'onchange' event of dropdownlist
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange = "return ChangeHeaderText()"
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Try this It will work......